Core-only specifications for whips & scourges
I'm looking for details pertaining to whips and scourges in the core of 2e. They're the only weapons with no weapon type (-- instead of bludgeoning/piercing/slashing) according to their entries on p.69 of the Player's Handbook (PHB). As far as I can tell there's nothing in the Dungeon Master's Guide (DMG) about them, so given the description of weapon type on PHB p.73 (weapon type only matters if using the weapon type vs. armor modifier rule on p.90), the best RAW ruling I can come up with is that they are just normal weapons not subject to that rule. The only other thing I can find about whips/scourges is a non-mechanical text entry for a scourge on p.74/75 of PHB.
I understand that the Arms & Equipment Guide (AEG) and Complete Fighter's Handbook (CFH) that clear things up with how the whip works, but I'm trying to avoid rules supplements and wondering if there's any RAW in the core set (PHB/DMG) that adjudicates this.

Looking at your question list, are you aware that you can accept answers if they answered your question, by clicking the green checkmark?

@NobodytheHobgoblin I was not aware, thanks for letting me know.

They are just normal weapons
As you already have observed, there is just no further text in the core rules discussing these weapons. Since the optional weapon type vs armor rules apply attack modifiers based on the type of armor and weapon, and these weapons have no type, those rules do not apply to them and do not modify the attack bonus.
I always thought that the whip was not meant as a fighting weapon in 2e core (the damage output sucks and it has no special combat rules, different from 5e), but rather as an instrument to punish without inflicting too much damage.
There is a magical whip in the DMG (p. 177), but that also does not provide a damage type, and its other properties are of course specific to this magic item.
